# Hacer referencia a la imagen actual img src

Tags: html

Tengo tres imágenes A, B y C que pueden tomar el valor de la imagen grande pulsando sobre la imagen grande (cargada por defecto con la imagen A).

Mi código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Index.html</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cambiarimagen.css"/>
        <link href="https://www.jose-aguilar.com/scripts/jquery/zoomy/zoomy.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.jose-aguilar.com/scripts/jquery/zoomy/zoomy.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function cambiarImagen(imagen) {
                /*Se obtiene el valor del id "grande". */
                var imagenGrande = document.getElementById("grande");
                imagenGrande.src = imagen.src;

                /*Se obtiene el elemento mediante la clase. */
                var aElement = document.getElementsByClassName("zoom")[0];
                /*El a href del valor actual es... */
                var aHref = aElement.getAttribute("href");
                /*El src de la imagen con id grande es... */
                aElement = aHref.src;
            }

            $(function() {
                $('.zoom').zoomy();
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <center>
            <br/><br/>
            <img class="peque" src="http://stadioalicante.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/seta-icono-new-super-mario-bros-wii-articulo-videojuegos-zehngames.png" onclick="cambiarImagen(this)"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <img class="peque" src="https://www.muycomputer.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/whatsapp-630x405.jpg" onclick="cambiarImagen(this)"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <img class="peque" src="https://ep01.epimg.net/verne/imagenes/2016/05/09/articulo/1462808367_678696_1462867491_rrss_normal.jpg" onclick="cambiarImagen(this)"/>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            <a href="http://stadioalicante.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/seta-icono-new-super-mario-bros-wii-articulo-videojuegos-zehngames.png" class="zoom"><img id="grande" src="http://stadioalicante.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/seta-icono-new-super-mario-bros-wii-articulo-videojuegos-zehngames.png"/></a>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

**¿Cómo hago para saber el valor actual del href y src de la imagen con id="grande" y que el zoom se realice por cada imagen?**

Sólo me acepta el zoom de la primera imagen, los restantes zoom también hacen referencia a la primera imagen (A) y no a las equivalentes.

Comment: Recomiendo que agregues el codigo de la funcion cambiarImagen()

Comment: El `src` de la imagen grande ya lo tienes, es `imagenGrande.src`. En cuanto al link, tendrías que obtener ese elemento y obtener su atributo `href`.

Comment: Un ejemplo explicativo por favor.

Comment: Como se obtiene de valor del atributo href de la imagen actual.

Comment: @omaza1990 Si hay algo que no se entienda de estos artículos: **[¿Qué son las etiquetas, y cómo debo usarlas?](/help/tagging)**; [¿Cómo etiqueto correctamente mis preguntas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1504/127); o [The Death of Meta Tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/); te invito a preguntar en [meta] algo como "*¿Por qué no está bien crear etiquetas como `[img]`?*" (y ahí podemos ver más en detalle el tema).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifiqué el código inicial para utilizar jQuery ya que estaba en el ejemplo actual y es más fácil de esta forma.

En este caso el zoomy no se actualiza con la imagen porque internamente en el primer llamado crea un elemento nuevo (div con nombre de clase zoomy), este tiene en el css, el background la imagen inicial del elemento .

Para solucionarlo, en la función solo borramos ese elemento cuando se cambia la imagen (y quitamos una clase de parent que se crea también desde ) y se vuelve a generar todo con .zoomy() que utiliza la imagen nueva.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Index.html</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cambiarimagen.css"/>
        <link href="https://www.jose-aguilar.com/scripts/jquery/zoomy/zoomy.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.jose-aguilar.com/scripts/jquery/zoomy/zoomy.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function cambiarImagen(imagen) {
                $("#grande").prop("src", imagen.src);
                $(".zoom").prop("href",  $("#grande").prop("src"));

                $(".zoomy").remove();
                $(".zoom").removeClass("parent-zoom");
                $('.zoom').zoomy();
            }

            $(function() {
                $('.zoom').zoomy();
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <center>
            <br/><br/>
            <img class="peque" src="http://stadioalicante.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/seta-icono-new-super-mario-bros-wii-articulo-videojuegos-zehngames.png" onclick="cambiarImagen(this)"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <img class="peque" src="https://www.muycomputer.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/whatsapp-630x405.jpg" onclick="cambiarImagen(this)"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <img class="peque" src="https://ep01.epimg.net/verne/imagenes/2016/05/09/articulo/1462808367_678696_1462867491_rrss_normal.jpg" onclick="cambiarImagen(this)"/>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            <a href="http://stadioalicante.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/seta-icono-new-super-mario-bros-wii-articulo-videojuegos-zehngames.png" class="zoom"><img id="grande" src="http://stadioalicante.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/seta-icono-new-super-mario-bros-wii-articulo-videojuegos-zehngames.png"/></a>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Esa parte del código ya la tengo realizada, la que me da error o mal sintaxis es la parte de hacer zoom. Hace zoom únicamente sobre la primera imagen, los restantes zooms también son sobre la primera imagen, y no sobre la equivalente.

Comment: @omaza1990 ya entendí el problema mejor, modifiqué el código de la respuesta arriba, de esta forma se realizan bien los cambios de imagen :).